# android NDK queries

Tags: android, android-ndk

I need to make use of a c++ file in my android project, say to add two numbers, the logic has been written in the c++ file.
I have eclipse and android NDK unzipped file alond with SDK with me.
Im familiar with android development.
Could some one pls help me out with the steps wrto NDk.
I have read online regarding cygwin  but couldnt make myself comfortable with that. Is it essential for the development and at the same time pls help me out with the steps
Any
a+b=c program to implement this would suffice , pls help with the setup as well

Answer (score 0):

Cygwin is not essential in the later versions of the NDK. With the NDK Eclipse plugin, you can set up your environment to build the native library every time you build the project. Download the NDK plugin, point it at the NDK folder, then right-click on the project and choose "Add native support".

Also, there's the `ndk-build.cmd` script in NDK; it's a Windows command file that does not require Cygwin.

As for the first steps in coding, look at the hello-jni sample. The most important takeaway is that C(++) code needs to be wrapped in specially named C functions for Java to consume it.